# Validating custom syntax

Tags: java, algorithm

In my application i have a custom syntax that the user can enter:
IF(ROW1>ROW2;4;ROW1+ROW2)
or something more complicated:
IF(ROW1>ROW2;IF(ROW1>ROW2;4;ROW1/IF(ROW1>ROW2;4;ROW1-ROW2));ROW1+ROW2)

i think it's clear what the output will be for the first exmaple:
if ROW1 is greater than ROW2 then the result will be 4 else ROW1+ROW2.

Whats the best way to validate this kind of custom syntax in java if I can't use any external libraries.
From what i've read RegEx won't help because it can't handle nested brackets.

My only idea is to:

- Valdiate if the brackets are balanced;
- Validate the neighbours of the operators (relational and calculation), there can be only rows, numbers, and in case of relational other IF statements;
- Finally validate the structure of the IF statement.(recursively);

All this will be done in a Parser that will go through each character one by one.

Is there a more smart idea of doing this validation?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create your own language. If that's the case, you can use something like ANTLR to generate a parser and lexer for you then just use that.

Comment: Also see Flex/JFlex family of tools and things like GNU Bison, although that may be more heavyweight than you are looking for.

Comment: Why can't you use external libraries?  What you're creating here is basically an interpreter (for a simple language).  This is a somewhat tricky, but solved problem.  Unless your goal is to learn how to write an interpreter, you're just inventing work for yourself by limiting your tools.

Answer (score 1):

If use of ANTLR is not as option as it was advised in comments, I would use stack and convert your expression [from infix to postfix form](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~vcss233/Projects/01/Infix2Postfix.pdf).

In the article in the link above only mathematical operations are observed, but you can extend possible operations in your code, adding `if`'s and comparison operators.

And after that you can evaluate your expression using stack.